# Imaginary part of a triple intragral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm only an introductory calculus student(I just finished my high school AP calculus BC course) so I apologize if these questions seem a bit elementary.

I'm using Mathematica to perform a triple integration(that I do not know how to perform myself). The integration I am trying to perform is:

$$
GM  \sigma \int_a^b  2 \int_0^\frac{L}{2} 2 \int_0^\frac{W}{2} (  \frac{-1}{ \sqrt{x^{2}+ y^{2}      +z^{2} } } dx dy dz.
$$

Where G, M, and Sigma are constants. (Gravitational constant, Mass of object 1, and the density of object 2)

This integration represents the integration of the gravitational potential equation, over an area in 3-space. However, when calculating this integration using Mathematica, There is an imaginary component (which always seems to have a net sum of 0)

the input is

```
Integrate[ -1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] , {z, a, b},
       {x, 0, L/2}, {y, 0, W/2},
       Assumptions -> {L > 0, W > 0 , z > 0, a > 0, b > 0 , b > a}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

the result is
[image: Long triple integral result]

My question is, where does this imaginary part come from? Also, Is there a way to simplify this equation (or create a more simple function which estimates the value with a high level of accuracy, similar to polynomial estimation for single variable functions)

Comment: The real question is.... Why are you using Mathematica for this.  This should be an easy computation to do by hand.  (btw, this is neither complex nor functional analysis so I removed these tags)

Comment: Thank you, I'm unaware with much of the terminology, so I was just trying to guess based on the prescriptions. As I've said, my calculus education is still pretty basic, I've barely looked at multi-variable equations. I do not know how to perform the equation by hand. You say it's simple, could you explain how it is done?

Comment: Sure give me a moment....

Comment: Much better in spherical coordinates. That way, it is no longer natural to have the volume be rectangular.

Comment: Use [Gauss-Ostrogradsky Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) with $\displaystyle{\large {1 \over r} = {1 \over 2}\,\nabla\cdot\left(\vec{r} \over r\right)}$.

Comment: Imaginary part probably came from wolfram's algorithm to solve this equation by throwing it into an algorithm involving complex numbers, I wouldn't be surprised if all imaginary terms get cancelled out at the end